# Getting values from Firebase in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get all `keys` from `ReceptIdOne` in `ArrayList` first and next get all   keys from `ReceotIdTwo` in `ArrayList`. My database has structure:

```
{
  "Receptes" : {
    "Ingridients" : {
      "IngridientIdOne" : {
        "Carrot" : true,
        "Salt" : true,
        "Apples" : true
      },
      "IngridientIdTwo" : {
        "Strawberries" : true,
        "Sugar" : true,
        "Bananas" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I try to get with my code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ingridientsRef = rootRef.child("Receptes").child("Ingridients");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String ingridient = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", ingridient);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ingridientsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

But I only get value `Ingridients` in my Logs. What I do wrong? How can I do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the keys inside `ReceptIdOne` then try the following:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ingridientsRef = rootRef.child("Receptes").child("Ingridients");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          Boolean carrot = (Boolean) ds.child("Carrot").getValue();
        //etc
        Log.d("TAG", ingridient);
    }
}

   @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
  };
ingridientsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Here you loop inside `recepIdOne` and retrieve the values there.